# "cd ~" で指定する ~ の意味は？

Tags: linux, centos, shell

VirtualBox にCentOSを入れてみました。
初めにrootでログインしたんですが、`root@localhost ~`となっています。`~` って何だろうと思って `cd ..` してから `ls` すると以下のファイル群が並んでいます。

```
bin dev home lib64 mnt proc run srv tmp var
boot etc lib media opt root sbin sys usr
```

ここには、`~` が並んでいないんですが、半信半疑で試しに `cd ~` とすると、また `root@localhost ~` に戻ってこれます。

この `~` とは何なんでしょうか？

Comment: カレントディレクトリは `pwd` コマンドで確かめられます。参考まで。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` とは、シェル (bash/sh/zsh) に対する引数において、ホームディレクトリとして展開してくれ、という指示を表す省略記号のようなものです。正式名称は [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) です。プロンプトで表示される `root@localhost ~` は、逆にシェルが、「今 `root` で localhost
 にログインしていて、カレントディレクトリは `~` (つまりホームディレクトリ) だよ」ということを伝えてきています。

一般的な linux ディストリビューションにおいては、 root ユーザーのホームディレクトリは `/root` に設定されています。なので、

- `~` から `cd ..`: カレントディレクトリがルートディレクトリ(`/`) になる。
- `cd ~`: `cd /root` と等価。

`bin` や `dev` は、ルートディレクトリ直下のディレクトリ群です。

Answer (score 3):

単に`~`を入力した場合は**自分自身が現在ログインしているユーザー**のホームディレクトリを指しますが、
`~USER`のようにチルダに続けてユーザー名を入力すると**指定したユーザ**のホームディレクトリを指すこともできます。

rootユーザーのみホームが`/root`に設定されていますが、一般ユーザーは`/home/`の下にサブディレクトリとしてホームが設定されることが多いので、例えば`taro`というユーザーが存在した場合は以下いずれかの形で参照することができます。

- /home/taro
- ~taro