# Linux (CentOS) でSDカードマウントのやり方

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

Linuxの学習環境として、Windows 10のパソコンに、VirtualBox 6.1 (CentOS 7) を入れて、
https://www.aps-web.jp/academy/wr-linux/18676/#YoctoLinuxWind_River_Linux
あたりの実験をしています。

この中の、

> 不要なファイルを削除し、設定ファイルを追加する

についてなのですが、

1. 「~」の意味
   `mkdir ~/broadcom`
   というのがありますが、「~」は何か特別な意味があるのでしょうか？
2. `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdX1 /mnt`
   というのがあるのですが、私の仮想マシンの中に、フォルダ：sdX1はありません。これを作るにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 『1. 「~」の意味』に関しては ["cd ~" で指定する ~ の意味は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38405/) が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: 参照している記事が本当にあなたのやりたい事に合致しているのかは、今一度確認した方がよさそうです。まったく無関係ではありませんが、「Linux の学習用」にはあまり向かない気がします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最終的な目的は、サーバー系linuxではなく、組み込みlinux（デバイスドライバなど）が最終目標であることはあるのですが、基礎を飛ばしすぎでしょうか。（私自身、そういう感じはしています。）

Answer (score 0):

`~` は「ホームディレクトリ」の別名です。ホームディレクトリが `/home/john` であるとき `~` は `/home/john` となります。 `mkdir ~/broadcom` なら `mkdir /home/john/broadcom` と同じ意味です。普通のユーザーならホームディレクトリ以下には任意の権限があるはずなので `mkdir` できるはず。

`/dev` 以下の一部のデバイスファイルは `/dev/sdX1` に限らず PnP のタイミングで自動生成されたり削除されたりします。なので真に SDcard が挿入されていないと存在しません。仮想マシンから見てホスト側物理デバイスは許可されない限り見えないので、手順としては

- SDcard をホストマシンに挿入する
- SDcard を仮想マシンから見えるように VirtualBox の設定で許可を与える
- もしかしたら VirtualBox のクライアント側 CentOS に Guest Addition を追加する必要があるかも

PnP 挿入時のデバイスファイル名が `/dev/sdX` とか違う場合もあるので、その辺は要確認。

Comment: 丁寧な、ご回答ありがとうございました。わかりました。